# AJAX working in jQuery 1.8.3, but not in 1.9.1

Tags: ajax, jquery

As described by the title, I have this AJAX function, that work perfectly in jQuery 1.8.3

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "bee.php",
  success: function(msg) {
     $("#bee-section").ajaxComplete(function() {
     $(this).html(msg);
  });   
  }
});
```

But not working in jQuery 1.9.1 and doesn't show anything at all. Any help? Thanks. :)

Comment: Not quite sure why you are using `ajaxComplete` vs just doing `$("#bee-section").html(msg)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) :

> As of jQuery 1.8, however, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be
>   attached to document.

You should use

```
$(document).ajaxComplete
```

instead of

```
$("#bee-section").ajaxComplete
```

But you don't need `ajaxComplete` here as you're already in the `success` callback.

Simply use

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "bee.php",
  success: function(msg) {
     $("#bee-section").html(msg);
  }
});
```

or even simpler :

```
$("#bee-section").load("bee.php");
```